# How to define inheritance relationship in LINQ Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, inheritance, ef-core-3.1

I am implementing a project by asp.net core.In sql server, I have a table called Applicant and it has got two children LegalApplicant and PersonApplicant both of which inherit from Applicant table and each of them has related attributes. Each of LegalApplicant and PersonApplicant tables has one to one relationship with Applicant table. I used DB first approach to scaffold them in visual studio. Now I want to define the relationship between them with linq. I appreciate if anyone could solve my problem. I;m new in EF core. And even I have problem in understanding the syntax.

```
   public partial class PersonApplicant:Applicant
    {
        public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
        public int ApplicantType { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string NationalCode { get; set; }
        public string BirthCertificateNo { get; set; }
        public string IssuePlace { get; set; }

        public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType ApplicantTypeNavigation { get; set; }
    }

public partial class LegalApplicant : Applicant
    {
        public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
        public int ApplicantType { get; set; }
        public string EconomicCode { get; set; }
        public string RegisterNo { get; set; }
        public string NationalCode { get; set; }

        public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType ApplicantTypeNavigation { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Applicant
    {
        public Applicant()
        {
            Apiapplicant = new HashSet<Apiapplicant>();
            LegalApplicant = new HashSet<LegalApplicant>();
            PersonApplicant = new HashSet<PersonApplicant>();
        }

        public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
        public int ApplicantType { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual EntityType ApplicantTypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Apiapplicant> Apiapplicant { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LegalApplicant> LegalApplicant { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PersonApplicant> PersonApplicant { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: write your code here.

Comment: *I used DB first approach to scaffold them in visual studio.* Well, that should have defined the relationships as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```cs
public class PersonApplicant : Applicant
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string BirthCertificateNo { get; set; }
    public string IssuePlace { get; set; }
}

public class LegalApplicant : Applicant
{
    public string EconomicCode { get; set; }
    public string RegisterNo { get; set; }
}

public class Applicant
{
    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicantType { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NationalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your `DbContext`, do something like this:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>();
}
```

This will make an `Applicants` table with a "Discriminator" column to differentiate which columns any one record should utilize.

> At the moment, EF Core only supports the table-per-hierarchy (TPH) pattern. TPH uses a single table to store the data for all types in the hierarchy, and a discriminator column is used to identify which type each row represents.

Reference: [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)